# ArangoDB inserts are extremely slow

Tags: node.js, performance, insert, arangodb

I just went from version `1.4` to `2.1.1` and noticed improvements, but still extremely slow insert rate that *gets slower as more documents are inserted.*

I am migrating from my old database to new and inserting 1000 at a time. Here are some logs for your perusal:

```
========= [26.28s]
BATCH #1 [0s]
========= [0s]
CREATED: 1000 [0s]
UPDATED: 0 [0s]
SUBTOTAL: 1000 [0s]
BATCH TIME: 26.279s [0s]
TOTAL BATCH TIME: 26.279s [0s]
AVG TIME PER BATCH: 26.279s [0s]
TOTAL TIME: 29.277s [0s]

========= [29.919s]
BATCH #2 [0.001s]
========= [0s]
CREATED: 2000 [0s]
UPDATED: 0 [0s]
SUBTOTAL: 2000 [0s]
BATCH TIME: 29.919s [0s]
TOTAL BATCH TIME: 56.198s [0s]
AVG TIME PER BATCH: 28.099s [0s]
TOTAL TIME: 61.341s [0s]

========= [33.698s]
BATCH #3 [0s]
========= [0s]
CREATED: 3000 [0s]
UPDATED: 0 [0s]
SUBTOTAL: 3000 [0s]
BATCH TIME: 33.697s [0s]
TOTAL BATCH TIME: 89.89500000000001s [0s]
AVG TIME PER BATCH: 29.965000000000003s [0s]
TOTAL TIME: 97.755s [0s]

========= [62.653s]
BATCH #10 [0s]
========= [0s]
CREATED: 10000 [0s]
UPDATED: 0 [0s]
SUBTOTAL: 10000 [0s]
BATCH TIME: 62.653s [0s]
TOTAL BATCH TIME: 438.422s [0s]
AVG TIME PER BATCH: 43.842200000000005s [0s]
TOTAL TIME: 474.096s [0s]
```

I'm using the [ArangoDB NodeJS API](https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB-JavaScript) and running the following code (1000 times for each batch):

```
db.document.create("users", user)
```

Is there something I'm missing here, or is ArangoDB a lost cause for any database with >1000 records?

Comment: To determine where the problem is (database server, node.js driver, connection), can you please try to run the following command and post the results here? `arangob  --test-case document --requests 1000 --concurrency 1 --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529`

Comment: Can you also check whether the collection you're inserting into has its `waitForSync` option set to `true`? If so, then each insert will trigger a full disk sync operation and wait until the OS has confirmed the sync is finished. This might be very slow, depending on the type of disk you use. If `waitForSync` is set to true for the collection or the individual save operation, can you try turning it off and retry the inserts?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look to the  property "waitForSync" of your collection. 
I've made following experience with waitForSync, creating 1000 documents and using the nodejs driver for arango:

```
waitForSync  true 13,3 s
```

```
waitForSync  false 0,5 s
```